# Mysql: Hyphen in like expression on json column

Tags: mysql, json, sql-like

I'm working on Hibernate query which fetches List of records and count in 2 separate queries. This query also has a functionality to pass SEARCH STRING to  filter data as per given search criteria.

Now I m facing a problem where I'm trying to search this given input on a JSON column. 
 Everything works fine when I try search any normal string containing only alphabets like 'Project ABC'. But the moment I introduce a hyphen (-) in search string, MySQL returns empty result for given HQL query. The problem occurs for column which has a JSON value stored in it as TEXT. Sample query is as below:

```
select *
from SERVICE_PROVIDER_TRACKER servicepro0_
where  (servicepro0_.requestParams like '%ProjectName:"%Order Lo-%"%'  or
        servicepro0_.REQUESTER_ID like '%Order Lo-%' or
        servicepro0_.PROVIDER_SALES_ORDER like '%Order Lo-%')
order by servicepro0_.REQUESTED_ON desc;
```

Here in above sample query, **requestParams** is JSON column. Even if I remove that column from condition, I still don't get any data.

I tried using *ESCAPE* IN *like* as well as *REGEXP*.

Can someone please help me with this?

Update :  Here is a sample JSON:

```
{
.............
NotifyEmailWhenResponseReceivedForBoq: "N",
termsConditions: "Y",
Currency: "1",
ProjectName: "Order-88",
BoMNameCreation: "Use Provider's BoM name",
............................
providerId: "com.yagna.common.domain.Orgnization:604"
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the actual JSON you are trying to select?  The only characters which have a special meaning in `LIKE` are underscore (`_`) and percent (`%`), and they would need to be escaped.

Comment: Maybe you don't have normal hyphen in your data, but some other (utf8) char which looks similar? (For example MS Word automatically changes all normal hyphnes to special chars like short hyphen and long hyphen.) Try to copy-paste the "hyphen" from your data into the query.